# How to produce a float from a string with only zeros after decimal place

Tags: javascript, floating-point

How do you produce `69.00` (float) from `"69.00"` (string)?

I've tried:

```
parseFloat("69.00")            // 69
parseFloat("69.00").toFixed(2) // "69.00"
```

Comment: errr, looks correct to me

Comment: Don't see any problem. `.00` will anyway be not displayed.

Comment: @Rahul,  its not that its stripped,  its still represented, its just 69.00 and 69 and 69.0000 and 69.000000000000  are the same thing.   How many decimal points you show is a printing problem which toFixed is all about

Comment: There is only one number type in JavaScript: IEEE-754 64-bit floating point. If you want to pad the decimal place to two zeroes for display then just use `toFixed(2)` like you are already using.

Comment: @KeithNicholas, with `stripped` I don't mean truncated but rather not displayed.

Comment: this question seems self answered

Answer (score 3):

Unless you actually have a value after the decimal point, the value of the float is just going to be 69. I do not understand why you would need this though, if you actually want to print the value of the float then you need to convert it to a string in which case you can add the two zero's if you want them to display as such.

Comment: This is not an answer, it's a comment. The reason I asked was because I'm curious, not because of any real world applications.

Comment: In a way, this is the answer.  As far as math operations are concerned, there is no difference between 69, 69.00, or 69.000000; they all resolve the same and therefore there is no reason to represent the actual value using extra decimals that mean nothing.  It is like setting an integer to 0000000000069 rather than just using 69.  It is only necessary to use those extra zero's when you are trying to visually display it, but in that case the value you display is no longer a number, but a string which follows different rules.

Comment: @KevinBeal: it is an answer, IMO. It answers your question. OK, in some languages, there are decimal types that preserve the decimals, i.e. in C#, 69.00m will be stored as 6900*10^-2, and the zeroes are preserved. This doesn't happen in floating point. 69.00 is stored as 1,078125 * 2^6. The number of decimal zeroes you see on screen is a result of the display functions.